# generate token in authentification

Tags: symfony

I want generate token with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle but I have this bug:

> atchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTManager::create() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, instance of MedBundle\Entity\Med given, called in /var/www/html/authenti/src/MedBundle/Controller/ApiController.php on line 53 and defined

this is code action login:

```
public function loginAction() {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
                $username = $request->request->get('username');
                $password = $request->request->get('password');

             $test = $em->getRepository('MedBundle:Med')->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

                if (!($test)) { var_dump('error'); } else{ 
                    $salt= $test->getSalt();
                    $pass = crypt($password,$salt);
                    if ( $pass === $test->getPassword() ) {
                    var_dump('success'); } 
                }

                $x = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager')->create($test);
                var_dump($x);
     }     
                return $this->render('default/login.html.twig');

        }
```

how to resolve this bug please

Comment: help help please :(

Comment: Does MedBundle\Entity\Med implement Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, ? Seems like that is the issue

Comment: I use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface but also bug :(